# Three column layout - aligment without float

Tags: html, css, layout

As I understand it in modern web-development horizontally aligning elements side by side is by using float (for example three column layout is achieved by floating two to one direction and one the other).  However this does bring out various problems and at the moment I am working on a website that require seperate columns in both header and content thus I need to float pretty much everything and set up various margins and widths to keep them from jumping all over the place.

With HTML5 and CSS3 on the rise I am wondering whether there is something to replace floating with easier solution?  As it is HTML5 and CSS3 introduce easier ways to make certain things happen (like rounding corners with border-radius) so one would think with multiple columns in a website being almost non-avoidable something to ease that hassle would be invented.

Comment: i dont get the issue here. `float`is used to side by side element. maybe you need to wrap your columns and use clearfix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's flexbox, or [CSS Flexible Box Layout Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/).

The spec seems to be reasonably stable as it has reached [Candidate Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/Process-20051014/tr#q74) status.  I don't know how good browser support is for this latest version.

Here's a [recent article](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/flexbox-revisited/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at any of the responsive frameworks like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html)? With a responsive framework, it's very easy to setup columns dependent on the screen size.

To my knowledge, there is no built in CSS property of columns beside creating your own with floats and dynamic widths.